# How to use "If else" condition with date in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

Hi guys so I have post and comment system, So I want to show comment section if the day of the post +7 days. if they see the post on day 8 of the post created they can't comment. Here is my code that I try but I still dont get it :

```
@if($comment['created_at'] <= 7)
    <a href="" class="btn orange-button">comment section</a>
@elseif($comment['created_at'] >7)
    <a href="" class="btn orange-button">Can't comment</a>
@else
    <span class="badge bg-pink">Hello</span>
@endif
```

I know it's totally a dumb code, hope you guys can help me I'm still learning here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has Carbon library

use like this

```
if (Carbon::now()->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($comment['created_at'])) > 7) {
    //cant comment
}
```

in blade

```
@if (Carbon::now()->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($comment['created_at'])) > 7)
    //cant comment
@endif
```

Comment: is it can implement in blade or I should use it on my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use The Carbon class is inherited from the PHP DateTime class like this :

`use Carbon\Carbon;
if($comment->created_at <= Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->toDateTimeString()){}`